# Android Studio: Cannot load class from tools.jar / major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, java-8, java-7, android-studio-2.1

it seems as if similar questions have been asked and solved, but I can't get the offered solutions to work.

I am using Xubuntu based on Ubuntu 14.04.5, and have several JDKs installed, all under `/usr/lib/jvm/. OpenJDK 6` and 7 were already installed by default, I added the official Oracle / Sun JDK 1.8.0_102, which I am intending to work with.

JAVA_HOME is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102` according to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/ (not much of an effort, though). Also, PATH includes `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_102/bin.`

On startup, Android Studio throws an error popup as seen in the screenshot.
(http://abload.de/image.php?img=screenshot-10.08.2016t4set.png)

I have also had a look into the config files of Android Studio, but could not make out what I could alter there.

Do you have any suggestions?

Kind Regards

Dennis

Comment: in android studio change java compiler to jdk 1.8 and jre to 1.8...sometimes compiler and jre version will be different(compiler should not be less than jre)

Comment: I think it's all setup correct. As I have said, I cannot start Android Studio itself but only edit the config files. I have checked jdk.table.xml, and all seems correct, especially the referenced paths. Anything that I could check in first place?

Answer (score 0):

Delete app/build folder
go to build and clean project and rebuild

Comment: I can't even launch Android Studio - after the popup error, the process is being terminated.

Comment: install openjdk-7-jdk